# Ignore setter and set property directly

Tags: kotlin

I have a class that writes a user to SharedPreferences every time it is set:

```
class UserManager @Inject constructor(
        val prefs: SharedPreferences,
        val jsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<User>
    ) {

    companion object {
        val USER = "user"
    }

    var user: User = User()
        set(value) {
            field = value
            prefs.edit().putString(USER, jsonAdapter.toJson(user)).apply()
        }

    init {
        val userString = prefs.getString(USER, null)
        if (userString != null) {
            user = jsonAdapter.fromJson(userString)
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem:** If the user is set in the init block, it calls the setter and writes the user that we just got from the shared prefs... to the shared prefs.

**Question 1:** How can I directly set the property from the init block?

**Question 2:** Why do I have to initialize the User when I define a custom setter, but can omit the initialization when the default setter is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to directily initiliaze the property with the correct value. You can do this using the `run` function from the stdlib:

```
class UserManager @Inject constructor(
        val prefs: SharedPreferences,
        val jsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<User>
) {

    companion object {
        val USER = "user"
    }

    var user: User = run {
        val userString = prefs.getString(USER, null)
        if (userString != null) {
            jsonAdapter.fromJson(userString)
        } else {
            User()
        }
    }
        set(value) {
            field = value
            prefs.edit().putString(USER, jsonAdapter.toJson(user)).apply()
        }
}
```

Shorter syntax proposed by Ilya Ryzhenkov on the Kotlin Slack:

```
var user: User = prefs.getString(USER, null)?.let { jsonAdapter.fromJson(it) } ?: User()
    set(value) {
        field = value
        prefs.edit().putString(USER, jsonAdapter.toJson(user)).apply()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the best solution is to use the 'backing property' concept described here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-properties

```
private var _table: Map<String, Int>? = null
public val table: Map<String, Int>
  get() {
    if (_table == null)
      _table = HashMap() // Type parameters are inferred
    return _table ?: throw AssertionError("Set to null by another thread")
  }
```

Then initialize the backing property in the constructor and do `<backingproperty> = value` instead of `field = value` as well as point the getter to the backing property.

Comment: I tested this and it works however I I find the solution of kirill more readable. Still have an upvote.

Comment: For me, since the initialization depends on something not yet calculated, I have to use backing property.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `by map` delegate, seems like this is the pattern you want:

```
class User(val map: MutableMap<String, Any?>) {
    var name: String by map
    var age: Int     by map
}
```

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#storing-properties-in-a-map